# Problem with setCenter in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver

I'm working with MapServer/PostGIS using OpenLayers to display map.  I'm trying `setCenter` `map` but it is not working!

My code:

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(107.567139, 12.326586, 108.258591,
        12.890796);
var options = {
    controls : [],
    maxExtent : bounds,
    maxResolution : 0.0010217594533836,
    projection : "EPSG:4326",
    units : 'degrees',
    allOverlays : true
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);
.....
//Declare some layers wms
.....
map.addLayer(wms_RanhGioi);
map.addLayer(wms_GiaoThong);
map.addLayer(wms_ATM);
map.addLayer(wms_Cafe);
map.addLayer(wms_KhachSan);
map.addLayer(wms_NhaHang);
map.addLayer(wms_TramXang);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({
    'ascending' : false
}));
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
    position : new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
}));
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')));
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
    element : $('location')
}));
map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(12.67812, 108.04401), 5);
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You just put the center coordinates in wrong order. Longitude should come first and then the latitude. In your code, the point is out of the maxExtent you set in map options.

Answer (score 1):

I have an extra (). Like this:

```
map.setCenter((new OpenLayers.LonLat(160000,485000)), 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with the map coordinate

```
var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(12.67812, 108.04401);
center.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
map.setCenter(center,5);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But it's not working! You can give me a demo of setCenter in OpenLayers!

Comment: Thanks to everyone!
I sloved problem!
It's 

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(108.04401, 12.67812), 5);

Instead

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(12.67812, 108.04401), 5);